# Typescript Passing Type to Generic Sub Class

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a class that inherits from two levels of abstract class. I'm wondering is it possible to pass generics from `Test` class to `BaseComponent` as it stands, or would the `BaseRendererComponent` need to be changed?

For example, if I wanted the `Test` class to pass down a `TestData` type to be used for `BaseComponent.baseData` type `A`

```js
export abstract class BaseComponent<A = DataType> {
  public baseData: A;
}

export abstract class BaseRenderComponnet<B> extends BaseComponent {
  public renderData: B;
}

export class Test extends BaseRenderComponent<BranchData> {
}
```

Comment: I made a little example with constrains on type, hopefully it can help you: https://tsplay.dev/wggK1w

Comment: i was trying to make a more complete example, the main point is that you can specify the type when you `extends BaseComponent` like `extends BaseComponent<B>`

Comment: You can't automatically pass generics down; you need to do it explicitly, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxYybW).  Does that address your question? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz maybe it can't be done without updating one or other of the `abstract` classes - but I updated my question to make it clearer what I am after

Comment: Sorry but I'm understanding this question even less now; what is `TestData`; where is that defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to specify the type of your `BaseComponent` when you extend it for your `BaseRenderComponent`, like this:

```
abstract class BaseComponent<A = DataType> {
  public abstract baseData: A;
}

abstract class BaseRenderComponent<B> extends BaseComponent<TestData> {
  public abstract renderData: B;
}

class Test extends BaseRenderComponent<BranchData> {
    baseData: TestData;
    renderData: BranchData;

    constructor(baseData: TestData, renderData: BranchData) {
        super();
        this.baseData = baseData;
        this.renderData = renderData;
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://tsplay.dev/wQVbvN

If you instead want to specify the type for both base and render component from your test, you could do it like this:

```
abstract class BaseComponent<A = DataType> {
  public abstract baseData: A;
}

abstract class BaseRenderComponent<A, B> extends BaseComponent<A> {
  public abstract renderData: B;
}

class Test extends BaseRenderComponent<TestData, BranchData> {
    baseData: TestData;
    renderData: BranchData;

    constructor(baseData: TestData, renderData: BranchData) {
        super();
        this.baseData = baseData;
        this.renderData = renderData;
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://tsplay.dev/N5eVMN